# Save Bash script output to text file with conditions

Tags: bash

I am using [this](https://github.com/IntellexApps/blcheck) script to check a list of ips I own to see if they are on the spam block list.

auto.sh:

```
while read ip ; do
    ./blacklist.sh $ip
done < block.txt
```

blacklist.sh is the above linked script.
block.txt lists each of my ips one line at a time (I have several /22).

A typical output of a blocked ip scan looks like this:

```
Warning: PTR lookup failed
b.barracudacentral.org : 127.0.0.2
bb.barracudacentral.org : 127.0.0.2
black.junkemailfilter.com : 127.0.0.2
cbl.abuseat.org : 127.0.0.2
cidr.bl.mcafee.com : 127.0.0.4
dnsbl.justspam.org : 127.0.0.2
hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com : 127.0.0.2

----------------------------------------------------------
Results for <my ip>

Tested:        117
Passed:        110
Invalid:       0
Blacklisted:   7
----------------------------------------------------------
```

what I want to do is have the script spit out output to a file when the text above doesn't say "Blacklisted:   0".

I am not sure how to approach this, will this work?

sudo ./auto.sh "conditions where Blacklisted: is > 0" >> 12.txt

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the output in a temporary file and
then check its content:

```
./auto.sh > 12_temp.txt
grep -q 'Blacklisted:[ \t]*0$' 12_temp.txt || cat 12_temp.txt >> 12.txt
rm -f 12_temp.txt
```

Comment: You need to store the result somewhere, so you can check its output. Instead of a temp file, you could also use a shell variable - it is only more complicated.

Comment: Thanks does almost exactly what I wanted. only I had to add double pipe before rm -r. like this: ./auto.sh > 12_temp.txt grep -q 'Blacklisted:[ \t]*0$' 12_temp.txt || cat 12_temp.txt >> 12.txt || rm -f 12_temp.txt. Other wise i was getting 'cat: invalid option -- 'f' Try 'cat --help' for more information.' error and 12.txt file was empty.

Comment: Unfortunately there is a formatting issue with this when opening as a text file. when I 'cat 12.txt' exactly like the above example in the my question but when I open it on a text editor, it looks like this https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pavs/83ea142c8cfecd882f9c/raw/8a207e0ed2b6ebe19b3f1315fe3dd1a254c238ca/gistfile1.txt

I think it might be due to how the formatting is handled in the original script: https://github.com/IntellexApps/blcheck/blob/master/blcheck#L458

Anything I can do to fix the output when opening the file in php?

Comment: Found the solution -p gives formatting in plain text.